# how to create jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to create a jar file for the .java program

followed the steps as

```
Step 1. Create a 'mywork' folder
Step 2: Put the XYZ.java and the gson.jar file under the mywork folder
Step 3. Use javac -cp .:gson.jar XYZ.class
Step 4. Create Jar File -> jar cf XYZ.jar XYZ.class
Step 5. Create a Manifest.txt and modify it to include MainClass:XYZ
Step 6. Modify Manifest.txt to include classpath for gson.jar
Step 7. Then run the command-> jar cfm XYZ.jar Manifest.txt XYZ.class argument1 argument2
```

when I am doing step 7 I am getting

```
"java.io.IOException: invalid header field" error
```

Where am I going wrong, please help me to solve the problem.

My Manifest.txt is like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:gson.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: XYZ
```

main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Enter the values for the arguments
    String dirstr = args[0];
    String logfiledirstr =  args[1];

        XYZ data = new XYZ();
        data.method1(dirstr,logfiledirstr);
}
```

Comment: What are your `argument1` and `argument2`?

Comment: @Mureinik    inputs are CSV files. Also Edited to include the main class.

Comment: a stacktrace might help in the disgnostic (or at least `XYZ` code)

Comment: only a shot in the dark but maybe 'Class-Path:gson.jar' is missing a space between the : and the gson.jar

Comment: @WilliamReed No space as well. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix value with space after the semicolon

change

```
Class-Path:gson.jar
```

to

```
Class-Path: gson.jar
```

viz http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Name-Value_pairs_and_Sections

value:SPACE *otherchar newline *continuation

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a "New Line" at the end of your manifest file.
Give a New line and then check.

Your file must be like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: gson.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: XYZ (Press Enter)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am not sure what does that mean?

Comment: @user3188390 it means open your manifest file, hit enter (to create a new line), then save it.

Comment: @Subodh : No it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I am just guessing now. Give a space between "Class-Path:" and "gson.jar" and try.

Comment: That's the format used by the Manifest file...Glad that it worked..:)